# Audio file duplicating when changing scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a audio player during scene 0 in my game (the menu). I have a code that intends to prevent the objects destruction when changing scenes. This works.. mostly. But for some reason, when moving to scene 1 a second audio player is created. This does not happen when moving to scene 2, 3, etc. I cannot find any components in scene 1 indicating a second audio player.
I have attached screen shots that may be of assistance. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am stumped.
[audio player and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSNUF.png) ....
[duplicated audio in scene 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYVJJ.png).... [image]

Comment: Do you have an instance of AudioTonight only in level0? And please, write a code that loads a level 1

Comment: @OnionFan The only instance I can find of AudioTonight is in level0. I have attached a photo of the code I use to move from the menu (level0) to level 1

Answer (score 0):

In your Scene Changing Script, Create a New Function (or edit existing function)
`LoadSceneWithoutAudioDestruction` or Whatever seems good to you
*Then Write down the Following Code.*

```
public GameObject AudioSouce; //in starting of file to reference Audio

public void LoadSceneWithoutAudioDestruction(){
DontDestroyOnLoad(AudioSouce);
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneNameasString);
}
```

Now on button which you want to Load next Scene attach this Script and ad function `LoadSceneWithoutAudioDestruction` to **On Button click Event of that button.**

*Also Ensure that the next scene that you are Loading does not habe any Audio Source Already*

If any Problem exists, ask me in comment.

Comment: Greetings, I have updated the script. I have included a picture above along with the error I get shown at the bottom of the photo. 
I appreciate your assistance in this matter!

Comment: Just Replace ```LoadSceneWithoutAudioDestruction``` on Line 22 with ```LoadSceneWithoutAudioDestruction( )```, **you forgot to add brackets.**